# LocalHost only showing files

Tags: visual-studio, localhost

[LiveServer Localhost:5500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSYUe.png)
Once I go into my localhost all I see are the files:
[LocalHost:5500 Only files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5tRs.png)

I'm sure it's a simple error but, I can't figure out what the issue is. I've tested other projects on localhost:5500 from my localhost and everything else works. So I'm thinking it's simply the project that has the issue. What could have caused this issue? I haven't made any changes for several weeks and it worked the last time I worked on it. I've looked online but, no one seems to have posted about this issue before. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

I tried opening the livserver to see the website and edit it.

Comment: This issue was resolved, the problem was that I was not using npm I to start the program.